# In IntelliJ IDEA, how do I use the keyboard to highlight an arbitrary checkbox?

Tags: intellij-idea

For example, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> to extract a parameter, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> on the resulting dialog box moves directly from "Name" to "Refactor". I know I can work around this by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> to select a checkbox (e.g., <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> for replace all), but as <kbd>AltGr</kbd> doesn't work I have to contort my left hand to hit this combination. How do I, using the keyboard, select the first checkbox, so I can use space to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to access the checkboxes in this dialog is via mnemonics (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>underlined letter</kbd>).

There is also an open issue to add tabstops for checkboxes and radio buttons in the refactoring dialogs so that they can be accessed not only by the mnemonics, but also by cycling the components using <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

- [IDEA-154127](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154127) Extract refactorings: navigation and mnemonics problems

There is really nothing you can do about it until tabstops are explicitly implemented for these dialogs.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! For now I've mapped the right Windows key to Alt, which gets around my AltGr issue.