# IntelliJ MacOs keyboard shortcut for checkbox toggle

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Many of the commands produce checkboxes. I would like to know of a keyboard shortcut that ticks/unticks a checkbox.

For example `CMD+OPT+Z` opens the “Rollback Changes” dialog box, using the tab you can scroll to all the files that have changed but I cannot find a way to tick/untick the checkboxes.

Note:This is on a MacOS using IntelliJ 2021.1

Thanks

Comment: You can try using mnemonics. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42703669/12844632 .

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion but I don't believe mnemonics could be used to selecte a checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

The <kbd>Space</kbd> bar work for me for selecting and deselecting checkboxes in the Rollback Changes dialog.